# Sugar maple transplant stress or root rot?

Tags: transplanting

I got a sugar maple moved with a tree spade last spring, it seemed to be doing great all last year. Last spring it's leaves looked normal, this spring they have a few yellowish streaks in most of them. They looked a little curled as though it was short on water so I watered it and the leaves uncurled. The thing that has me concerned is the slight yellowish streaks that remain in the leaves, will they stay all season this season or are they a symptom of root rot or some other condition I should watching for or treating?

[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you take a photo on the other side? Do you have a lens? Could you check if you see mites/spiders?

Comment: I think it probably just needed some water XD

Comment: @Giacomo it appears there are some sort of eggs in the most recent photo I added. They're just tiny little red dots at this point. There are a few leaves with holes chewed through them.

Answer (score 2):

The last photo is out of focus.

For me they are "just" pick from spider mites. The red one could be galls.

Usually there is nothing to worry about it. The leaves are still green, so plant will not be much affected.

On a tree, it is also difficult to handle it.

The usual rules: check it, but do nothing. This is usually the best solution. If the situation will be much worse, you may use an insecticide. But usually it is much better to let nature to control it. Rival insects usually will keep control on that. The problem: it you use too many insecticides (and fungicide) you may kill the rival insects, so the situation could become worst, so more insecticides and so on.

On vineyards and orchids, some additional plants are sometime used to keep the rival insects (e.g. roses). But on gardens this should not be needed (you should already have many different species).

Note: both spider mites and antagonists could live in many different species. This complicates [you should spray all vegetables] (and it makes also easier [antagonists should be nearby]) to fight them.

Comment: Note: I'm not an expert of sugar maple. So take what I said with some grains of salt.